# Consolidate Spark Logs

Tags: log4j, apache-spark

I would like to be able to get a consolidated view of my spark jobs.

I am using log4j on the machine that creates the RDD, and the various jobs that get distributed are also using log4j. This ends up with a local log file, and then log files on each node the job was distributed to.

Is there some built in way to bring all of these logs together? Having to look both on the server machine + each node is painful.

I've looked around a bit, and possible two options seem to be:

1. Use something like JobLogger (using Spark Listener).
2. Using a socket appender, or something like Flume

What's everyone's experience on dealing with distributed logs?

Comment: Have you tried [LogMX](http://www.logmx.com)? It can merge several log files in a single view and monitor this merged view in real-time (supports SCP/FTP/SFTP/HTTP/...)

Comment: Might be able to use something like that - but I'm really trying to find something Spark-centric if possible, or the most common practice in the Spark world, to do this.

Right now, I've created a program that I can pass the app job id and it will go to all the nodes in my cluster (via ssh) and copy the stdout and stderr files local...

Comment: Hey Greg, did you find any solution for your problem? I have a similar requirement, any insight would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I ended up creating a custom script that did this - pass in a list of hosts, and it pulls all the logs.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want this, you may try to put logs in some shared directory, but I don't think it is a good solution. I don't know why you need such functionality - mixed logs from different executors working in parallel and even from different applications can make your logs really messy.

Comment: I'm running one job over multiple workers.  I want to get a consolidated view of what happened (e.g., one log message might just be on the log for one worker).

Answer (score 0):

If you create a logger and pass it to your workers with the processes, the workers can write to a consolidated file on the master node. An example in Python (using explicit multiprocessing):

```
import logging
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
LOG_FILENAME = '/home/hadoop/logs/filename.log'    logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger('pyspark')

p = ThreadPool(numNodes)

logDFs = p.map(lambda x: foo(logger, ...), listOfStuff)


def foo(logger, vars):
     #do stuff
     logger.info('This appears in your consolidated log on master.')
```

Running in the pyspark framework, the workers pickup the processes and the function `foo` passes the logger to it. You can see the log statements from the workers in the logs folder on the master node.